# HTML Button Redirect

Tags: javascript, html

I am wondering if there is a straight-forward way to add a redirect for an HTML button?

From my research, the best way seems to be: `<button onclick="location.href='/'">`, but it violates content security policy, since `onclick` is considered to be an inline event handler. I know that I can do the `onclick` on a separate JS file, but I have quite a bit of buttons, and it would be tedious to write some JS codes for each one. Another approach is to use the `<a>` tag and uses `href` directly. But again, that requires me to change all the buttons to `<a>` tags, and again I have a lot of buttons.

Comment: Are you kidding? It's usually less code, more reusable, and more logical, to write a separate JavaScript file to handle everything.

Comment: Write a single, delegated event which covers all the buttons. https://javascript.info/event-delegation

Comment: Semantically, a button should not redirect, screenreaders are transcripting the meaning of the button incorrectly, if it redirects. A link is meant to redirect, a button should just perform an action on the current page, unless its type tells the button will actually redirect (type of submit).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just one possible solution to give you an idea:

Handling your buttons in another file could be as easy as this:

JS:

```
document.querySelector( 'div' ).onclick = ( e ) => {
  if( e.target.dataset.href ) {
    window.location.href = e.target.dataset.href
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div>
  <button data-href="/">Navigate</button>
  <button data-href="/bla">Navigate</button>
  <button data-href="/bli">Navigate</button>
  <button data-href="/blu">Navigate</button>
</div>
```